# Returning Disposable from Subscribe method for an Observable

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a question on Observables ([which I posted](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/43336.page;jsessionid=6466D84DD7C47B41BB3DA7A1BA882A93) on the publishers sub forum for this book but I am still waiting on any response).

I use the helper methods provided as is the standard practice rather than handcrafting the observables. However just out of academic interest I did see into what it takes to handcraft an observable.

I saw an implementation in a book where at the end of subscribe method Disposable.Empty was returned.
The code is somewhat like below.

```
public class MyObservable : IObservable<int>
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            observer.OnNext(i);
        }
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }
}
```

If I want to return a proper Disposable which will actually lead to unsubscribing when Dispose is called what should be the way?

I had a crack at it using this for the [Observable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-implement-a-provider) and this for [Observer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-implement-an-observer)

I had to introduce a subscription handler

```
public class SubscriptionHandler : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<int>> _listOfObservers;
    private readonly IObserver<int> _currentObserver;

    public SubscriptionHandler(List<IObserver<int>> currentListOfObservers, IObserver<int> currentObserver)
    {
        _listOfObservers = currentListOfObservers;
        _currentObserver = currentObserver;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_currentObserver != null && _listOfObservers.Contains(_currentObserver))
        {
            _listOfObservers.Remove(_currentObserver);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the Observable

```
public class MyObservable : IObservable<int>
{
    private List<IObserver<int>> _listOfSubscribedObservers = new List<IObserver<int>>();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        if (!_listOfSubscribedObservers.Contains(observer))
        {
            _listOfSubscribedObservers.Add(observer);
        }

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                observer.OnNext(i);
            }

            observer.OnCompleted();
        });

        return new SubscriptionHandler(_listOfSubscribedObservers, observer);
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that I am missing something. There has to be a built in way to return a meaningful Disposable for handcrafted Observable or this is something which comes only with Observable create helper methods?

Comment: Have a search for "Rx design guidelines" Some of the syntax is out of date, but basically you should make observables either by composing existing ones or by using Observable.Create.

Comment: I think you've already figured it out, but when you see `return Disposable.Empty;` in code like this then it is probably a poor implementation.

Comment: @Enigmativity In the defence of the author he just gave an example of handcrafting the observable and then quickly denounced the idea of handcrafting it. Rather strongly advised to stick with standard operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should make clear that all of this is a demonstration of Rx design internals. You can have a look at classes [`AnonymousObservable<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/AnonymousObservable.cs),
[`AnonymousObserver<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/AnonymousObserver.cs), and [`AnonymousDisposable`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Disposables/AnonymousDisposable.cs), which is how the framework does it. Pretty straight forward. However, you should almost never use any of this code, rather use things like `Disposable.Create` and `Observable.Create`. If you're implementing an `IObservable`, you're almost definitely doing it wrong.

Here's the basic idea: The observable needs to produce an `IDisposable` which removes the relevant observer from the observable's internal list of observers. Your code is (wrongly) removing *all* observers from the internal list.

Here's a basic disposable which makes it easy to create functionally. With this code, `GenericDisposable.Create` is the same as `Disposable.Create(Action a)`.

```
public class GenericDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public static IDisposable Create(Action disposeAction)
    {
        return new GenericDisposable(disposeAction);
    }
    
    private readonly Action _disposeAction;
    public GenericDisposable(Action disposeAction)
    {
        _disposeAction = disposeAction;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposeAction();
    }
}
```

...and here's an example observable implementation:

```
public class SendIntMessages : IObservable<int>
{
    private readonly HashSet<IObserver<int>> _observers = new HashSet<IObserver<int>>();
    
    protected void OnNext(int i)
    {
        foreach (var o in _observers)
            o.OnNext(i);
    }

    protected void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        foreach (var o in _observers)
            o.OnError(e);
    }

    protected void OnCompleted()
    {
        foreach (var o in _observers)
            o.OnCompleted();
    }

    public void SendIntMessage(int i)
    {
        OnNext(i);
    }
    
    public void EndStream()
    {
        OnCompleted();
    }
    
    public void SendError(Exception e)
    {
        OnError(e);
    }
    
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        _observers.Add(observer);
        return GenericDisposable.Create(() => _observers.Remove(observer));
    }
}
```

This is a long-running, hot observable. It keeps track of its observers, and the disposable unsubscribes them.

Consider in contrast this observable:

```
public class CountTo5 : IObservable<int>
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        observer.OnNext(1);
        observer.OnNext(2);
        observer.OnNext(3);
        observer.OnNext(4);
        observer.OnNext(5);

        return GenericDisposable.Create(() => {});
    }
}
```

This is a 'cold' observable that runs immediately. There's no way to unsubscribe in the middle: By the time you get the disposable, the observable has concluded.

`Disposable.Empty` is a simple short hand for `DisposableCreate(() => {})`.

Comment: Honestly you should get paid for this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My takeaway is that there is no out of box way to return a meaningful Disposable for handcrafted Observable, which in the first place we should not be doing. Rather stick to the provided ways. Sweet.

Comment: @NotAgain - I'm not sure of any handcrafted observables that need to be done in the way your question asks - you can just use out of the box operators. Do you have an example of one that can't use standard operators?

Comment: @Enigmativity It was more of an academic question. I stick to the standard operators. In all the examples I saw of the handcrafted observables illustrating the concept, the IDisposable part of the story was left out.

Answer (score 0):

To return a meaningful `IDisposable` to the caller, you should not generate all notifications synchronously during the subscription. You should generate them asynchronously on a different context, and return to the caller immediately a subscription that has not completed yet. Here is a way to do it, by using the `Task.Run` method to invoke the notifications on the `ThreadPool`:

```
public class MyObservable : IObservable<int>
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
                observer.OnNext(i);
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
        }, cts.Token);
        return new CancellationDisposable(cts);
    }
}
```

The [`CancellationDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh212123(v=vs.103)) class...

> Represents a disposable resource that has an associated `CancellationToken` that will be set to the cancellation requested state upon disposal.